# WKInterfaceMap Unknown Location

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I added a WKInterfaceMap object to our Apple Watch app.  When I press it to get directions, it always says "Unknown location" but gives the right directions.  How can I get it to populate with the name of the location?

Comment: it appears that only location "known" to Apple's Maps will show the location name. This includes the locations it pulls in from Yelp. Anything else is just an "Unknown Location"

Comment: Any update on this with watchOS 3?

Comment: Has there been any update for this question?  I am seeing the same issue but I don't see any way to set the title of the specified location when opening the Maps app on the watch.

Answer (score 5):

Yep Like RPM is saying, for now if apple "maps" does not know the location's name, it tells "Unknown location"...

if your location is to an know location, like yelps locations, it will display the location name...

i hope that Apple will implement a way to set the title of the location...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I ran across it recently and we just now came up with a solution. We added a tap gesture recognizer to the WKInterfaceMap in the interface builder, dragged its selector to a function in the interface controller. In that function add:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: center, addressDictionary: nil)
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapItem.name = "Name of location"
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: nil)
```

Comment: If the map is on a dynamic notification you will need an interactive dynamic notification to be able to add the gestureRecognizer. Interactive dynamic notificationis available on WatchOS5 or later - just tick the checkbox in Interface Builder to add one